# How can I calculate the number of identical bits between my approximation of pi (π) and its real value?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, c++, algorithm

I've used Simpson's rule to approximate the value of pi. Now I want to determine how many bits are identical between the approximation I calculated and the real value of pi.

Here is how I approximate pi's value:

```
function simpson(f, n, a, b) {
    var h = (b - a) / n;
    var sum = f(a) + f(b);

    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
        sum += 4 * f(a + i * h);

    for(var i = 2; i <= n - 1; i += 2)
        sum += 2 * f(a + i * h);

    return h * sum / 3.0;
}
```

Comment: Please pick one language unless you want a language agnostic algorithm.

Comment: You could `XOR` the two and bits that are the same turn to zeros.  Difficulty, making fixed point numbers from your two values.   Might I suggest looking at the log base 2 of the difference between pi and your approximation.   The integer part will be the number of bits away from the binary point (analogous to decimal point) differences are.  `float bits = log( pi - approximation)/log(2);`

Comment: I assume that by "the real value of pi", you mean "the closest approximation of pi in a particular floating-point representation".

Comment: Come to think of it you better make that `log( abs( pi - approximation )/ log( 2 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a *XOR* operation on both the exact and calculated values, then count the number of zero's in the end result.

Also calculate the index of the first bit counting from the MSB of the exact value + 1 - this is the number of redundant padding zeros in the number. Take this away from the previous result.

Of course this depends on the precision of the data structure used. Also I'm sure this works in all languages you've tagged *apart* from JS.